# change ehlo name of Amavis

Tags: smtp, ubuntu-12.04, postfix, spamassassin

Server: Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit
Setup Postfix + Dovecot + Amavis with Mysql for Virtual domains.

I have configured the postfix mailserver successfully. However when I test the Email with mail-tester.com, i see following error

> FSL_HELO_BARE_IP_2    IP used in the HELO request The hostname should be
>   a domain name, not an IP RCVD_NUMERIC_HELO    Received: contains an IP
>   address used for HELO

The server has correct hostname and ptr configured and the EHLO is correct. . However when we connect to Amavis, its showing as 127.0.0.1

Telnet to server ip

```
# telnet 85.10.199.8 25
Trying 85.10.199.8...
Connected to 85.10.199.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.savelgo.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo localhost
250-mail.savelgo.com
```

Telnet to Amavis

```
# telnet localhost 10024
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 [127.0.0.1] ESMTP amavisd-new service ready
ehlo localhost
250-[127.0.0.1]
```

Can I somehow change this to my server hostname?.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly how did you "test the Email with mail-tester.com"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton : If you visit mail-tester.com, they will give an email address to which we need to send a mail. They will analys the our mail give results. You can see our test here:
http://www.mail-tester.com/web-itmkQw

Comment: Do you really mean to be virus-scanning _outgoing_ mail?

Comment: @MichaelHampton : Yes, Amavis is used for Virus scanning. And in the mail header, details of Amavis scanning available, which i guess is causing the problems.

Answer (score 2):

Set `$localhost_name` parameter in your config file.

```
$localhost_name = 'somedomain.tld';
```

Comment: Thank you. I have following configuration files. Can you tell me to which one I add the localhost_name variable?

# ls  /etc/amavis/conf.d
01-debian,     
15-av_scanners,               
20-debian_defaults,  30-template_localization, 
05-domain_id,  
15-content_filter_mode,       
21-ubuntu_defaults,  
40-policy_banks,
05-node_id,   
25-amavis_helpers,   
50-user

Comment: Not an issue, you can add to any one of them.

Comment: I added "$localhost_name = 'mail.savelgo.com';" to  "50-user" and restarted amavis and postfix, still the same.
Seems not working

Comment: There is [related bug #535437](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=535437) in debian packages (for long time).

Anyway you should add this change to 50-user so your change isn't overwritten in next update.

Answer (score 1):

To change smtpd banner you should set the "$smtpd_greeting_banner" variable.

```
$smtpd_greeting_banner = 'host.example.com ESMTP';
```